# Drupal Form States - How to notify a change in select?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms

I'm using a select that works with Drupal states. When a user selects certain a value it shows more information. It works fine with direct user interaction.

My problem is that when I make a change in the selector value programmatically nothing happens. I tried firing a change event in the selector, used prop, attr, click... nothing works.

How can I notify Drupal that I'm changing my select control so Drupal fires the appropiate state?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Using the change function had worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find which event drupal listen to for every input type in this function **ajax_pre_render_element($element)**

for form selects it is the **change** event, firing it is dependent on your jquery version

try

```
$('#id').val("1");
```

or

```
$('#id').prop('selected', true);
```

or

```
$('#id').change();
```